# Where is the Prothean Sphere in the Hades Nexus area?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm trying to find the Prothean Sphere in the Hades Nexus System, but I cannot really find it since all the system are invaded by Reapers and so I cannot scan quietly. (tried many times, many games over without having results from the scan)

**Can someone could tell me on which system and planet is it exactly?**
This will enable me to rush to the planet, retrieve the artefact and flee before the reapers catch me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the probe on **Gei Hinnom** planet in the **Sheol sector**.
Which is, as you might now, in the Hades Nexus System.

Good luck evading the reapers!!
(Otherwise you can wait their awareness get lower)

Comment: Gei Hinnom is the planet closest to the star.